Why is WordPress adding a "}" to the end of an external URL, breaking the URL?
I'm creating a CTA to an external page and WordPress is changing/breaking the URL by adding a } at the end of the URL.  I tried manually typing the URL to make sure there were no hidden characters.  The URL ends with .com/webcasts/register.cfm?eventid=939 but directs to .com/webcasts/register.cfm?eventid=939}

If the external page is"redirecting" as you mentioned, this has nothing to do with your WordPress site. Redirections happen server side on the targeted URL. As long as the URL is correct in your website's source code then this out of your control. Now, if you inspect your site's source code and you see the added bracket then there is an issue on your end. In which case you need to tell us how you are adding the URL to the site (Gutenberg, classic editor, other) and you'll need to try disabling your theme and 3rd party plugins to see which is causing the issue.
